# Prototype recursion function in callback

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following function in a prototype object:

```
EmptyChild:function(node)
{

     if (Array.isArray(node.children)) {
        node.children = node.children.filter(
            function(child) {
                if (child['id'] =="" || child.length) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    this.EmptyChild(child);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

but i get the following error:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'EmptyChild'
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is the global object in your callback. You need to save yours in a variable or to pass it to `filter`.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

> If a thisObject parameter is provided to filter, it will be used as
>   the this for each invocation of the callback. If it is not provided,
>   or is null, the global object associated with callback is used
>   instead.

So your code can be :

```
   if (Array.isArray(node.children)) {
        node.children = node.children.filter(
            function(child) {
                if (child['id'] =="" || child.length) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    this.EmptyChild(child);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        , this); // <===== pass this
    }
```